# Solr re ranking of results is not working as expected

Tags: solr

Dear solr community members,

I have a question related to re-ranking of my results from solr.

**Problem:**
I have a set of filters in a multifield like below in each document along with other fields.

```
{filters_multi_string :["A:H", "B:H", "C:N"]},
{filters_multi_string :["A:N", "B:H", "C:N"]},
{filters_multi_string :["A:H", "B:N", "C:H"]},
{filters_multi_string :["A:H", "B:H", "C:H"]},
{filters_multi_string :["A:N", "B:N", "C:N"]}
```

on the page user will be presented with filters A, B, and C. A:H means it's high-quality product where as A:N means a secondary quality product, the same applies to
other filters B and C. So now when selecting a filter we should show the quality products first and then secondary quality products.

**I tried the following:**
I want to achieve this by using the ReRank query parser (Query re-ranking in solr). Currently, we are having big complex
query which gives us results by applying different other filters and combinations, now on top of this query I want to re-rank the results using the re-rank query parser.
But somehow the results are not as expected.

Below is my example query when user selects filter A: `(my complex query)&rq={!rerank reRankQuery=$rqq reRankDocs=100 reRankWeight=20}&rqq={!lucene df=filters_multi_string v=$v1}&v1=A:H^20`
With the above query, I expect all my results from the first query to be boosted with high-quality products and show on top of the result set, but it did not work as expected and there is no change in the results at all.

Can someone help me with this? and please let me know if there is any other approach than this.

Comment: Have you looked at what scores gets assigned to the queries? The `A:H` part will only re-score the matching documents, so any other documents will still have the original score. If that score is higher than what `A:H^20` produces, nothing is going to change.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply @MatsLindh but the thing is that there is no change in the score at all even after applying the rq along with my actual query. The multifield I am using in rq is just a multi-string field, maybe it is something to do with the type of field?